# Populating rank in a different way

Tags: sql, teradata

I have below data in my table -

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD
111 555 1-Jan   5-Jan
111 555 5-Jan   9-Jan
111 222 9-Jan   15-Jan
111 555 15-Jan  20-Jan
111 222 20-Jan  1-Feb
111 333 1-Feb   10-Feb
111 333 10-Feb  1-Mar
111 333 1-Mar   4-Mar
111 444 4-Mar   31-Dec
```

I want to populate columnE in table and it should look like below -

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC ColumnD ColumnE
111 555 1-Jan   5-Jan   1
111 555 5-Jan   9-Jan   1
111 222 9-Jan   15-Jan  2
111 555 15-Jan  20-Jan  3
111 222 20-Jan  1-Feb   4
111 333 1-Feb   10-Feb  5
111 333 10-Feb  1-Mar   5
111 333 1-Mar   4-Mar   5
111 444 4-Mar   31-Dec  6
```

I want to start counting from 1st row(lowest date of ColumnB), if value is same assign the same count, if value is changing increment the value. 
In row#4, 555 is repeating again but i want to assign it value 3 because its not a repetition. Assign the same value only if value is same as exactly last one.

I am working on this in teradata.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a gap-and-islands problem.  One solution uses a difference of row numbers:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by seqnum - seqnum_b, columna, columnb) as rank
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by columna, columnb order by columnc) as seqnum_b,
             row_number() over (order by columnc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```